# Add jQuery .draggable() to TinyMCE image

Tags: jquery, tinymce, draggable

I created a plugin to ajax images and you tube embedded videos into a TinyMCE editor.
This works great but I can't find a way to attach the .draggable() j Query event to the ajax-ed image inside the editor.

I have tried: (I wrapped the imaged in a div with class dr)

Binding a mouse-down event and then setting `$(".dr").draggagle();`.
Applying it directly to the class.

The closest I got was the following code in the tinyMCE init code:

```
 ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
        alert('Editor was clicked: ' + e.target.nodeName);
 });
```

But I can't applay the `draggable()` to the `e.target\e.target.nodeName` for the life of me.

Any ideas?

Comment: please include the code you use to insert the ajax-ed image into the editor.

Comment: Try to look at http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that tinymce is not equal the editors source html element (for example a textarea) `$(".dr").draggable();` won't address the desired element. You will have to use `$(ed.getBody()).find(".dr").draggable();` to get the desired result.

Mark: Let me know if this suits you well or not ( it works on my system ).

Update: Make sure you call the dragable after tinymce is initialized other wise it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap a div around the image and specify its width and height. Then apply jquery draggable function within live function for example:

```
$('#mydiv').live(function(){$(this).draggable()});
```

Comment: can you please explain what is wrong in here who have downvoted this. I really appreciate the effort. I need to learn more for perfection